# Double clicking icons on the desktop doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchscreen

I installed 3M MT7.13 Touchscreen software on win7 x64. Immediately after I did I lost the ability to double click an icon on the desktop using the mouse (not the touchscreen). Also, in save/open dialogs and media player double clicking will rename the file instead of open/play/save it. I uninstalled the 3M software and defaulted the mouse settings and am still having the same issue. Although when changing the mouse to use single clicks the problem disappears and reappears when set back to double click. I ran SFC /scannow and it came back clear. I ran virus scan, it came back clear. I have a feeling that it is something to do with the registry settings.

3M do not seem to want to reply to my questions.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you in advance,

Mozez

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the uninstall of 3M MT7.13 failed to remove a driver that was conflicting with the mouse driver. So I had to use Driver Cleaner to get rid of the 3M driver properly. Once cleared the system returned to normal.